# How to use epubjs for android app using html5 ? / How can we configure epubjs to read the epub files from locally with out using XHR?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, epub, epub3

I created a sample application using epub js  with nodejs and HTML5 for reading the epub files from the server. Now I am trying to make this application as a standalone andriod/Iphone app .
But as per my understanding , every request in epub.js is XHR .

Can any body please guide me on this ? How can i create android app using html5+epub file using phonepag ?

I found couple of links which says it can be done, but no body says how it can be done.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: After unzipping epub files , i was able to read it locally only using the mozilla. But it is not working for Chrome/IE